# Parse TimeZone and remove the Country/State in Java

Tags: java

I need to get the System DateTime but do not need the [America/New_York] using the below code.
Any suggestions?

```
    String timestampAtGMT = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(Instant.now());
    String dateInAmerica = timestampAtGMT.trim();
    System.out.println("In 'GMT-04:00' Time Zone:" + dateInAmerica);
```

Code Output : 
In 'GMT-04:00' Time Zone:2020-03-23T21:39:49.419-04:00[America/New_York]

Expected Output : In 'GMT-04:00' Time Zone:2020-03-23T21:39:49.419-04:00

Comment: The code needs to be agnostic to Country/State. It can be of any location DateTimestamp depending on the system that triggers it.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to remove `.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`, and then change `Instant.now()` to `OffsetDateTime.now()`. With this, your new snippet looks like:

```
String timestamp = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(OffsetDateTime.now());
System.out.println("In 'GMT-04:00' Time Zone: " + timestamp);
```

And the output is:

```
In 'GMT-04:00' Time Zone: 2020-03-23T21:52:10.794463-04:00
```

By default, `OffsetDateTime#now` uses your system clock's default time-zone, so there's no need to specify it.

Comment: Good answer. As a matter of taste I would still prefer to pass `ZoneId.systemDefault()` as argument to `now()` to make it explicit that this is a time zone dependent operation and that I have chosen with open eyes which time zone i want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is an `OffsetDateTime` and no formatter. Simply:

```
    String dateInAmerica
            = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString();
    System.out.println("In 'GMT-04:00' Time Zone:" + dateInAmerica);
```

When I ran this with my JVM’s time zone set to America/New_York just now, the output I got was:

> In 'GMT-04:00' Time Zone:2020-03-24T15:53:11.948127-04:00

An `OffsetDateTime` is a date and time with an offset (for example -04:00), but without a time zone such as America/New_York. So you get the correct offset for your time zone at this time without getting the time zone.

Technically we could leave out `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but I prefer to state it there to tell the reader and myself that I have considered which time zone I want and have made a conscious choice to rely on the JVM default.